# What's the value of this limit?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

What is the value of the limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \ x\tan^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

I think you have to use the sandwich theorem (squeeze theorem) but I'm not sure and can't solve this by myself. Thanks for helping in advance.

Sorry forgot the squared symbol
Edit xtan^2(1/x)

Comment: This function isn't even defined in a deleted neighborhood of $0.$ How could it have a limit there?

Comment: Hint: take $x_n ={1\over{\pi/2+2n\pi}}$, this may hep to find if the limit exist

Comment: Are you sure the limit exists?

Comment: Limit of a product is equal to the product of the limits. Therefore check the limit of $f(x)=x$ and then check the limit $g(x)=tan(\frac{1}{x})$. Since the limit of $g(x)=tan(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist, and the limit of $f(x)=x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is $0$, your limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Stefan By your logic, $$\lim_{x\to 0} 0$$ does not exist, because we can take $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\tan \frac1x$. Then, the limit of $g(x)$ does not exist, and the limit of $f(x)$ is $0$, so the total limit (by your own words), does not exist.

Comment: @5xum I don't see how in your example that you just gave there is a $g(x)=tan(\frac{1}{x})$. I only see a $f(x)=0$. The limit you gave does not have $g(x)=tan(\frac{1}{x})$ as a product...

Comment: @StefanT. You claim: "If $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ is not defined, then $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is not defined." My example shows that that claim is **false**. Yes, in the **particular** case when $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\tan \frac1x$, the **conclusion** of the claim is true. But the claim itself is still wrong. i.e., your argument is not correct.

Comment: @5xum You're right.

Comment: @StefanT.: I think that 5xum is right! The product limit theorem state that if both of the functions have limits then the their product has a limit which equals the product of their limit. I think you made a mistake while trying to negate this theorem. :)

Comment: Should it maybe be arctan^{2}(1/x) instead of tan^{2}(1/x)?

Comment: @H.R. Yeah he is, I admit haha. I jumped to a conclusion.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass no I think it's tan, from what I can see

Comment: @SinisterCutlass it's from a practice test from a couple years ago

Comment: A similar practice question was like xsin(1/x) lim x approaches 0

Comment: @BrianTung I don't think it does the question was out of 5 so we need to explain the logic in saying it doesn't exist in a formal way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit does not exist. Note that $f(x) = x^2 \tan (1/x)$ equals $0$ when $x = 1/(k\pi)$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $1/(k\pi)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$, so if the limit is anything, it must be $0$.

However, let $\varepsilon = 1$.  Then we cannot find a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)$ is even defined (let alone within $\varepsilon$ of $0$) for $x \in [-\delta, \delta]$.  Observe that $\tan^2 (1/x)$ is arbitrarily large whenever $x$ is close to $2/[(2k+1)\pi], k \in \mathbb{Z}$; in particular, it can be made larger than $1/\delta$ for any $\delta > 0$, so we can always find a value of $f(x)$ within any interval $[-\delta, \delta]$ whose absolute value is greater than $1$.